# I have a button where the text is in span, how to find it?

Tags: xpath

Actually its not a button ( it acts as a button) but a text(i.e a domain name) where when a user click on it, it will go to next section .

This is the html:

```
<div id="domainCon2TitleLabel" class="tLabel">
<span>qa.xyz.com</span>
</div>
```

I have tried giving the xpath as

```
wd.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'qa.xyz.com')]")).click();
```

but showing error as

> Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//span[contains(text(),'qa.xyz.com')]"}

can any let me know how to identify the xpath for that span.

Comment: Works for me too. Check if this span is not located inside the iframe.

Comment: its not in iframe , is there any alternate way to get it.

Answer (score 3):

Try the xpath expression:

```
//*[text()[contains(.,'qa.xyz.com')]]
```

Comment: if it works remember to accept the answer this way it would shareable with others